# If list has values, append them to another list, else append predefined value

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have a list A, which I want to grow depending on some values in list B. I want to append B to A, and in the case B is empty, I want to input a predefined value to indicate this.

```
if B:
    A.extend(B)
else:
    A.append('no value')
```

This code does exactly what I want, but my only problem is that it doesn't look very pythonic. I'm pretty sure there must be a way to do this in one line where the if-else statement is in the list comprehension, something like:

```
A.extend([[x for x in B] if B else 'no value'])
```

This line almost works, but it in the case `A = []` and `B = [1]`, I end up with `A = [[1]]`, which does not work for what I want to do.

Any ideas how to make this work?

Comment: Do you want `A.extend(B if B else ['no value'])`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass a *list* with the default value; there is no need for a list comprehension here either:

```
A.extend(B or ['no value'])
```

I used `or` here because an empty list is considered false in a boolean context; it is more compact here and avoids repeating yourself.

The conditional expression version would be:

```
A.extend(B if B else ['no value'])
```

Comment: Brilliant! Exactly what I wanted!